# Angular select model not setting value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I have an array of strings, that are account numbers. When a record in a table is clicked i provide a modal to update the record and one of the fields is account number. This displays and some what correctly but seems to loss its two way binding with vm.accountNumber but also does show the value that the model is.

vm.accountNumber always has a value that is set when the table row is being clicked for editing. It just never makes it to the select despite the model. I suspect im losing the two way link and it is creating its own variable for the model.

```
  <select class="ui search fluid selection dropdown" id="accountSearch" ng-model="vm.accountNumber">
          <!--ng-options="account for account in vm.accounts.slice(1)">-->
          <option ng-repeat="account in vm.accounts | limitTo: vm.accounts.length : 1" value="account" ng-selected="account == vm.accountNumber">{{account}}</option>
  </select>
```

Here is a snippet of the accounts array.
0:"-"
1:"0001"
2:"0002"
3:"0003"
4:"0004"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say just use `ng-options` directive instead of `ng-repeat`ing `option`

```
<select class="ui search fluid selection dropdown" 
    id="accountSearch" ng-model="vm.accountNumber"
    ng-options="account for account in vm.accounts">
</select>
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/9ckIBIYTDRO6nuzb4Zu0?p=preview)

---

Though I'd like to point out your problem was with option value attribute,

you should change

```
value="account"
```

to

```
value="{{account}}"
```

Comment: While i agree i like the ng-options, you can see commented out i attempted the options as well and then even tried doing a ng-selected expression. Neither worked. The value didnt change anything but thanks :)

Comment: may I know what is `vm.accounts.slice(1)`? can you please also add `vm.accounts` json in question?

Comment: That is just skipping the first result which is "-". Updated question with array.

Comment: @user1552172 don't do that slice operation over there. do it on controller side, it will remove one item per digest cycle..and as per your dummy data I can say after 5 digest cycle nothing will be there..

Comment: @user1552172 added plunkr, could you please check it?

Comment: It works in the plunkr but not in my code, only difference is the value of accountNumber is not initially there only when clicked then a modal pops up and no value is selected.

Comment: @user1552172 you also wanted to pre select some value?

Comment: Yes, all the function does is update vm.accountNumber which is the model of the select and that should match up.

Comment: It seems to be working for me [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/9ckIBIYTDRO6nuzb4Zu0?p=preview) , I had `$timeout` instead of ajax which set value after 3 seconds.. could you please reproduce the issue in plunkr

Comment: In plunkr it worked fine, some how the vm.accountNumber in my code is losing its two way binding. It keeps the value i select in the html and if i click another table row it shows the old value despite me doign vm.accountNumber = somevalue in the controller.

Comment: Understood, im going to mark your answer because it should work.

Comment: @user1552172 still try to replicate in plunkr, I can surely help you on that. Thanks :-)